# Find specific elements by class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and I have an array of strings that are classes of different elements,

```
let melody = ['a', 'c', 'f', 'g']
```

I am doing a piano and this is a list that conform a melody that should find each element that has the same class and play it getting the final melody. I would normally do it with something like (obviously with an interval and other stuff)

```
    melody.forEach(note=> {
document.getElementsByClassName(note)[0].click()
})
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve this in react, and if using getByClass if correct to use in cases like this. Thank you so much....

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Basically you want to invoke a function associated with clicking on a certain key based on the array of notes in the `melody` array. Instead of triggering click on the element, there must be some kind of abstraction where you call the method to play the note directly, no?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html. You shouldn't be using native DOM methods to handle the DOM updates/checks as React has a specific way of doing that.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add notes to an array in state when a piano key is clicked, and then play those notes later when you click a "play" button to call a `playTune` function. This will iterate through the array in state and play each note in turn.

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise the use of modern DOM syntax.

```
let clickButton = document.querySelectorAll('.note');

let melody = ['a', 'c', 'f'];
    
melody.forEach((note) => {
    let newNote = document.querySelector("." + note);
    newNote.addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert("Hello world");
    });
});
```